# ARKit SKVideoNode Playing on Render

Tags: swift, avplayer, arkit, scnnode, skvideonode

**Main Problem:**

I am adding this section AFTER to clarify the problem. -- I can PAUSE my video (I do not want it playing on a loop). When my node comes into sight, my node plays my video, even if it is on pause. If my video has finished playing, and it comes into sight, it will restart. I want to REMOVE this behavior.

In my app, I have a `SKVideoNode` created from an `AVPlayer(:URL)` inside 3D Space using `SCNNode` objects and `SCNGeometry` objects. I use `ARKit` `.ImageTracking` to determine when a specific image is found, and play a video from there. All is good and dandy, except that the player determines to play on its own time, every time the AVPlayer comes into sight; however, it could be whenever the `ARImageAnchor` the `SCNNode` is attached to comes into sight. Either way, the `AVPlayer` is playing every time the node comes into sight of the camera lens. I use

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if(keyPath == "rate") {
        print((object as! AVPlayer).rate)
    }
}
```

to print out the rate, and it is 1, however, it was 0.

**I printed out some sort of print function `print("Play")` for all of my functions utilizing player.pause() or player.play() and none of them are called whenever the rate is changed above. How can I find the source of what is changing the rate of my player?**

I checked the original rootnode, `self.sceneview.scene.rootNode.childNodes` to make sure I am not creating extra VideoNodes/SCNNodes/AVPlayers, etc, and it seems that there is only 1.

Any ideas on why the SKVideoNode/AVPlayer is playing as the SCNNode comes into sight of the camera using ARKit? Thanks in advance!

**Edit1:**

Made a workaround, to determine ONLY when a user clicked on this node

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self!.tapGesture))
tap.delegate = self!
tap.name = "MyTap"
self!.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

and then inside of this next function, I put

```
@objc func tapGesture(_ gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tappedNodes = self.sceneView.hitTest(gesture.location(in: gesture.view), options: [SCNHitTestOption.searchMode: 1])

    if !tappedNodes.isEmpty {
        for nodes in tappedNodes {
            if nodes.node == videoPlayer3D {
                videoPlayer3D.tappedVideoPlayer = true
                videoPlayer3D.playOrPause()
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if(keyPath == "rate") {
        print((object as! AVPlayer).rate)
        if(!self.tappedVideoPlayer) {
            self.player.pause() //HERE
        }
    }
}
```

where videoPlayer3D is the `SCNNode` that contains the SKVideoNode.

However, I get the error `com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer (17): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d8f7ad0)` on the section labeled "HERE" above. It seems that the renderer of the sceneview is attempting to alter my video node in the render function, although, I don't even use the `renderer(updateAtTime:)` function, I only use

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    createVideoNode(imageAnchor)

}
```

to determine when I see an image, i.e., `imageTracking` and I create the node. Any tips?

**Thought 1**

The error is presented stating that some method is being called from an SCNView object for the method renderer (that's what I'm understanding from the error), but I don't have the node specifically called. I think maybe a default action, as the node is coming to view, is being called, however, I'm not 100% sure on how to access it or determine which method. The objects I'm using are not SCNView objects, and I don't believe they inherit from SCNView objects (look at the 1st paragraph to see the variables used). Just looking to remove the "action" of the node playing every time it is in view.

**ADDITION:**

For the sake of following the creation of my video player if interested, here it is. Let me know if there is anything else you'd like to see (not sure what else you might want to see) and thanks for your help.

```
func createVideoNode(_ anchor:ARImageAnchor, initialPOV:SCNNode) -> My3DPlayer? {

    guard let currentFrame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame else {
        return nil
    }

    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    var videoPlayer:My3DPlayer!
    videoPlayer = delegate.testing ? My3DPlayer(data: nil, currentFrame: currentFrame, anchor: anchor) : My3DPlayer(data: self.urlData, currentFrame: currentFrame, anchor: anchor)

    //Create TapGesture
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapGesture))
    tap.delegate = self
    tap.name = "MyTap"
    self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return videoPlayer
}
```

My3dPlayer Class:

```
class My3DPlayer: SCNNode {

    init(geometry: SCNGeometry?) {
        super.init()
        self.geometry = geometry
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    convenience init(data:Data?, currentFrame:ARFrame, anchor:ARImageAnchor) {
        self.init(geometry: nil)
        self.createPlayer(currentFrame, data, anchor)
    }

    private func createPlayer(_ frame:ARFrame, _ data:Data?,_ anchor:ARImageAnchor) {

        let physicalSize = anchor.referenceImage.physicalSize

        print("Init Player W/ physicalSize: \(physicalSize)")

        //Create video
        if((UIApplication.shared.delegate! as! AppDelegate).testing) {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Bear", ofType: "mov")
            self.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        }
        else {
            let url = data!.getAVAssetURL(location: "MyLocation")
            self.url = url
        }
        let asset = AVAsset(url: self.url)
        let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        self.player = player
        var videoSize = track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)

        videoSize = CGSize(width: abs(videoSize.width), height: abs(videoSize.height))
        print("Init Video W/ size: \(videoSize)")

        //Determine if landscape or portrait
        self.landscape = videoSize.width > videoSize.height
        print(self.landscape == true ? "Landscape" : "Portrait")

        //Do something when video ended
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

        //Add observer to determine when Player is ready
        player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [], context: nil)

        //Create video Node
        let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)

        //Create 2d scene to put 2d player on - SKScene
        videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoSize.width/2, y: videoSize.height/2)
        videoNode.size = videoSize


        //Portrait -- //Landscape doesn't need adjustments??
        if(!self.landscape) {
            let width = videoNode.size.width
            videoNode.size.width = videoNode.size.height
            videoNode.size.height = width
            videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoNode.size.width/2, y: videoNode.size.height/2)
        }

        let scene = SKScene(size: videoNode.size)

        //Add videoNode to scene
        scene.addChild(videoNode)

        //Create Button-look even though we don't use the button. Just creates the illusion to pressing play and pause
        let image = UIImage(named: "PlayButton")!
        let texture = SKTexture(image: image)
        self.button = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
        self.button.position = videoNode.position

        //Makes the button look like a square
        let minimumSize = [videoSize.width, videoSize.height].min()!
        self.button.size = CGSize(width: minimumSize/4, height: minimumSize/4)
        scene.addChild(button)

        //Get ratio difference from physicalsize and video size
        let widthRatio = Float(physicalSize.width)/Float(videoSize.width)
        let heightRatio = Float(physicalSize.height)/Float(videoSize.height)

        let finalRatio = [widthRatio, heightRatio].min()!

        //Create a Plane (SCNPlane) to put the SKScene on
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: scene.size.width, height: scene.size.height)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = scene
        plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

        //Set Self.geometry = plane
        self.geometry = plane

        //Size the node correctly
        //Find the real scaling variable
        let scale = CGFloat(finalRatio)
        let appearanceAction = SCNAction.scale(to: scale, duration: 0.4)
        appearanceAction.timingMode = .easeOut

        //Set initial scale to 0 then use action to scale up
        self.scale = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
        self.runAction(appearanceAction)
    }

    @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: Notification) {
        self.player.seek(to: .zero, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
        self.player.seek(to: .zero, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
        self.setButtonAlpha(alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

**Efforts1:**

I have tried to stop tracking via:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    createVideoNode(imageAnchor)
    self.resetConfiguration(turnOnConfig: true, turnOnImageTracking: false)   
}

func resetConfiguration(turnOnConfig: Bool = true, turnOnImageTracking:Bool = false) {
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    if(turnOnImageTracking) {
        guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else {
            fatalError("Missing expected asset catalog resources.")
        }
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
        configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
    }
    else {
        configuration.planeDetection = []
    }
    if(turnOnConfig) {
        sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking])
    }
}
```

Above, I have tried to reset the configuration. This only causes it to reset the planes it seems, as the video is still playing on render. Whether it is paused or finished, it will reset and start over or continue playing where left off.

**Efforts2:**

I have tried

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    createVideoNode(imageAnchor)
    self.pauseTracking()  
}

func pauseTracking() {
    self.sceneView.session.pause()
}
```

This stops everything therefore the camera even freezes as nothing is being tracked. It is completely useless here.

Comment: can we see `createVideoNode` plz. Normally we add video node as child of node in `didAdd node`.

Comment: How does the creation of where I add my node affect that my video be played every time it comes to view? Even if it is on pause.

Comment: Not sure , just my guess, there must be some logical issue if it plays everytime imageAnchor is found.

Comment: I added it for kicks and giggles

Comment: Where's the code for your ARWorldTrackingConfiguration used here? Would it be an option for you to stop the 'detection' once the video started playing?

Comment: Interesting!!!!! Let me think on that @Mihai and determine if I need to do that. That is phenomenal. I'll get back to here within 12 hours.

Comment: @MihaiErős how would I stop tracking without stopping the camera?

Comment: Not necessarily part of the main problem here, but you don't need to go to the trouble of setting up a SpriteKit scene and `SKVideoNode` — you can assign `AVPlayer` directly to the `contents` of a SceneKit material in iOS 11.0 and later.

Comment: I’ll look into that. Maybe that will also fix a problem. Will do that in a bit. Thanks for that @rickster

Comment: @impression7vx you can stop the tracking without stopping the camera using: ``let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration() 
config.planeDetection = []
sceneView.session.run(config)``

Comment: I was thinking that if you stop tracking, you won't be adding new nodes, that should help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. So here is a fix. see `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)`.

```
var player: AVPlayer!
var play = true

@objc func tap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if play{
        play = false
        player.pause()
    }else{
        play = true
        player.play()
    }
}

func setVideo() -> SKScene{
    let size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)
    let skScene = SKScene(size: size)

    let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video.mp4", withExtension: nil)!
    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

    skScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

    videoSpriteNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
    videoSpriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    videoSpriteNode.size = size
    videoSpriteNode.yScale = -1
    skScene.addChild(videoSpriteNode)

    player.play()

    return skScene
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    if let image = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{
        print("found")

        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: image.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: image.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        let plane = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
        planeGeometry.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = setVideo()

        plane.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-.pi/2, 1, 0, 0)

        node.addChildNode(plane)
    }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    if !play{
        player.pause()
    }
}
```

Use this idea in your code.

Comment: What if the video is paused? That's my problem. I DON'T want the video to be on a loop. I want the ability to pause it. WITHOUT the system PLAYING my video everytime it comes into view

Comment: If my problem was keeping the video playing, this would be easy. As it already does this. I want to pause my video and ONLY play it when I click on the node implementing a gesture type action.

Comment: Will try it and let you know!

Comment: You sly dawg. I used `renderer(_:updateAtTime)` for VARIOUS other activities in my app but never considered the possibility of this. This worked by adding the `if! play { player.pause() }`. Great workaround, however, the natural behavior for Apple needs to be changed. Thanks for this, seriously. Have had this problem for a while